# IIS Manager does not write logs to a shared storage as part of a Failover cluster

Tags: iis, failovercluster

I have a hosts say (b and c) as part of a failover cluster with SAN (d) and DNS/DC (a).

The config for IIS is stored in a SAN `\\d\config`. Similarly, the logs for the IIS is stored at `\\d\iis_logs\`.

I have one website W3SVC1. So, the log directory will be as follows: `\\d\iis_logs\W3SVC1\u_ddyymm.log`.

At first, when cluster is set up 'b' server is the primary server and 'c' is a failover, therefore 'b' will serve any requests to the cluster IP and logs will be written to the above mentioned directory by server 'b'.

Now, when I server b goes down, server c will start serving requests that come to the cluster IP. But the server c IIS doesn't write logs to the same file. I assume that server 'b' had a lock on the log file, hence it wasn't writing, but even after shutting down server 'b', server 'c' still doesn't write to the log file. No errors reported in Event viewer. How do I fix this? without configuring separate log storage for both applications

Comment: Is server d a windows system? If so, then you can try to use Process Monitor to see where the problem is. about how to use the process monitor you can refer to this link:[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: Server d is openfiler ESA

Comment: what about IIS version and SAN info?

Comment: Is the problem reproducible when you configure it the other way around (c as main and b as failover)? Is server c configured correctly so it can access the logfiles at all?

Comment: Yes, reproduces in all scenarios. And IIS 7.0 in windows 2008.

I think it is because of a permission issue, I need a solid answer.